# Password protect an entire directory with PHP authentication

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, .htaccess, passwords

I want to password protect an entire directory and authenticate users though a MySQL database using PHP. I know you can password protect directories using .htaccess but I can't seem to find out how to use PHP and MySQL along with that.

Answer (score 3):

When using [Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) or [Digest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) authentication to protect a folder, you are usually authenticating against a file on the server. That's probably why you didn't find any tutorials on using this with MySQL. You would have to use `mod_auth_mysql` to make this work from an .htaccess file.

See

- http://www.widexl.com/tutorials/htaccess.html#auth_mysql
- http://www.diegonet.com/support/mod_auth_mysql.shtml
- http://modauthmysql.sourceforge.net/CONFIGURE

A very basic example to do it without .htaccess and `mod_auth_mysql` can be found at

- http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-82.html

It should be noted that the script is not properly sanitizing the user input and it is also not using any encryption for the password. It's **not** a good script, but it has everything to get you into the right direction.

Also see the PHP manuals chapter on [HTTP authentication with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php).